# Deserialize list of key / objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This seems to be an easy question,
yet I haven't been able to solve it or find any solution.

How to deserialize this :

```
    {
    "1": {
        "a": "123",
        "b": "B1"
    },
    "2": {
        "a": "456",
        "b": "B2"
    }
  "3": {
        "a": "789",
        "b": "B3"
    }
}
```

into a list of objects :

```
MyObject{
public string a { get; set; }
public string b { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can deserialize it as `Dictionary<int,MyObject>`

```
using System.Text.Json;
// ....
var objs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int,MyObject>>(file);
var listValue = objs.Select(o=>o.Value).ToList();
```

but the above Approach is not recommended if you're going to interpret it as a list, so your json should be represented it as a list from the beginning

Comment: Thank you this is it, maybe it was too much obvious :)